# if i import header file the file containing definitions is also imported?

Tags: c++, modularity

I have defined the function signatures in a .h file. And the definitions (body) of the function in .cpp file. Will I be able to use the functions if I import the .h file ?

Comment: Are you asking about `import` or `#include`? `import` is a new mechanism, introduced in C++20.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the main purposes of header files (to reuse function declarations for multiple "source" files).

Comment: You will, provided you also take the appropriate steps when building your program to link the function definitions. Beginners sometimes think that all you need to do is include a header file, but you also need to link with the compiled function definitions.

Comment: If the header doesn't have the function bodies, you've *declared* (not *defined*) the function in the header.

Comment: Making the header file like you described is one of the steps to be able to use those functions in an other .cpp file. The other remaining step is to link all .cpp files together, and how exactly you do that depends on the IDE/compiler you use.